# DateTime shows random date after being bound to DataGrid

Tags: c#, wpf, nullable

I have an `ObservableCollection<object>` that I bind to a `DataGrid` in code behind and I add columns and generate bindings for those columns in the code behind as well.

```
   private void RgvReportDisplay_Loaded( object sender, RoutedEventArgs e )
        {
            if (RgvReportDisplay.Columns.Count == 0)
            {
                foreach (var item in ((ReportsQueryHolder)DataContext).Collection[0].GetType().GetProperties())
                {
                    Binding B = null;

                    if (item.Name.ToLower().Contains("date") || item.Name.ToLower().Contains("scheduledpickup"))
                    {
                        B = new Binding(item.Name + ".Date");
                        //B.Converter = new DateConverter();
                        B.Mode = BindingMode.OneWay;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        B = new Binding(item.Name);
                        B.Mode = BindingMode.OneWay;
                    }

                    RgvReportDisplay.Columns.Add(new Microsoft.Windows.Controls.DataGridTextColumn()
                    {
                        Header = item.Name,
                        Binding = B 
                    });      
                }
            }
        }
```

When I look at a Collection list prior to the being bound the dates look correct. Here is something from my Immediate Window:

```
((ReportsQueryHolder)DataContext).Collection[0]
{DataTableType}
    Amount: "749.00"
    Collector: "John Smith"
    CreatedDate: {3/11/2014 8:00:39 PM}
    LocationName: "QUICK STOP "
    LocationNumber: "37"
    ScheduledPickup: {3/12/2014 12:00:00 AM}
```

My dates are getting messed up. My dates now say random things when it gets bound to the DataGrid. Here's whats being displayed:

```
     10/12/8524
```

So some how 3/12/2014 is being converted to 10/12/8524.This once worked but now does not.

**ADDED:**

So it turns out that I was binding a `nullable` `DateTime` and that was causing the issue. Why would declaring those fields are `DateTime?` cause this?

Comment: Which dates do you see in the grid if you *don't* add the `DateConverter` to the `Binding`?

Comment: Hmmmmm...its the wrong date showing in the grid without the converter...I guess that eliminates the `DateConverter`...

Comment: Well, I guess that there's something unsafe going on. The `Nullable` "variant" of the type means there's a boolean field before the actual `DateTime` data. This would explain the shift in value quite nicely - there's a `bool` prefix to the date time data :)

Comment: I ended up handling the null in my date converter because NULL shows up as DateTime.MinValue therefore I just checked for that and then returned a string based on that...Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up handling the null in my date converter because NULL shows up as DateTime.MinValue therefore I just checked for that and then returned a string based on that